# Bash command to see a list of all open buffers

Tags: bash, buffer-list

I am in bash and emacsclient is running. I would like to run a bash command to display a list of all open emacs buffers. The output of buffer-menu is fine.  These commands do not work:

emacsclient -e "buffer-list"

*ERROR*: Symbol's value as variable is void: buffer-list

emacsclient -e "buffer-menu"

*ERROR*: Symbol's value as variable is void: buffer-menu

Comment: `buffer-list` and `buffer-menu` are functions.  Function calls have the form `(function args...)`, so you could use `emacsclient -e "(buffer-list)"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
emacsclient -e '(buffer-list)'
```

Comment: Even better, try the following: `emacsclient -e '(buffer-list)' | sed 's/>/>\n/g' | tee buffer-list.txt`

Comment: Oh, yes. Pipe to whatever processing is needed outside emacs.